# Return null into output parameter of dbtype.date

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I have a stored procedure which returns a date or null into a command parameter. However, I am having difficulty handling the null returns.

The procedure looks something like this:

```
PROCEDURE GetDate(inParam IN VARCHAR2, outDate OUT DATE) AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(DateVal) INTO outDate
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Col1 = inParam;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
        outDate:= NULL;
END GetDate;
```

And my VB.NET code looks like this:

```
Dim returnDate As Date

Connection.Open()
Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Command.CommandText = "GEN_PACKAGE.GetDate"
Command.Parameters.Add("inParam", inParam).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
Command.Parameters.Add("outDate", OracleDbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
returnDate = CDate(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value)
```

However, using this I get exception `Conversion from type 'OracleDate' to type 'Date' is not valid.` on `returnDate = CDate(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value)`.

If I change `OracleDbType.Date` to `DbType.Date` (which I found as a solution from another answer) I get `Value does not fall within the expected range` on `Command.Parameters.Add("D0131Date", DbType.Date).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`.

How can I return a date for a given input when my return date may or may not be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, can't test. No Oracle

```
    Dim returnDate = If(Command.Parameters("outDate").Value = DBNull.Value, Nothing, Command.Parameters("outDate").Value)
    If returnDate Is Nothing Then
        'Handle a null return
    Else
        Dim MyDate As Date = DirectCast(returnDate, Date)
    End If
```

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer. It's not the exact the way I did it in the end but handling of null parameter was the trick. I handled this using TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your procedure's exception block as

```
EXCEPTION 
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
        outDate:= date'1900-01-01';
```

to return a very old date, and treat this spesific value to filter out within your application as a null value by some `if` or `case` statements with collation with `outDate`'s value.

Comment: That's certainly an option, and I have considered it, but doesn't seem like the best way to go about this... Hopefully there's a more elegant solution available.

Comment: I've tried this but I still get `Value does not fall within the expected range` when using `DbType.Date`. Any ideas?

Comment: @WSC the value already mustn't be in your range, you need to except this value like a null. The main idea is not to corrupt the format for the returning variable, and keep it as date.